# MS Access / SQL Joining Large Data Sets

Tags: sql, database, performance, ms-access

I am trying to run a check to see that if 4 Columns in Table A are the same as the 4 in Table B then test if the value in the 5th column in both is the Same. (For 20,000-40,000) records in each table.

I have tried doing this in access but it seems to hang and I can understand why considering the data sets are quite large.

I've tried Joining on the 4 Columns in question and I've tried concatenating the 4 in each and comparing the concatenations. The problem is it both hang and don't return a result.

Can anyone advise on the proper / a better approach to this problem?

The only thing I could think of would be ordering the data first, but that could be slow and I don't know if Select queries exit early.
Thank you in advance.

Too Slow 1

`SELECT  TableA.ColA, TableA.ColB, TableA.ColC, TableA.ColD, TableA.ColE, TableB.ColA, TableB.ColB, TableB.ColC, TableB.ColD, TableB.CoLE 
FROM TableA INNER JOIN Table B ON(TableA.ColA = TableB.ColA, TableA.ColB =TableB.ColB, TableA.ColC = TableB.ColC, TableA.ColD = TableB.ColD)`

Too slow 2
 
`SELECT DISTINCT TableA.ColA & TableA.ColB & TableA.ColC & TableA.ColD AS C1, TableB.ColA, TableB.ColB, TableB.ColC, TableB.ColD AS C2,
TableA.ColA, TableA.ColB, TableA.ColC, TableA.ColD, TableA.ColE, TableB.ColA, TableB.ColB, TableB.ColC, TableB.ColD, TableB.ColE
FROM TableA, Table B
WHERE TableA.ColA & TableA.ColB & TableA.ColC & TableA.ColD = TableB.ColA & TableB.ColB & TableB.ColC & TableB.ColD`

Edit: Is there a better way to do this kind of check?
Edit: Got Too Slow 2 to run, but it took 12.5 minutes of "not responding"

Comment: Use `AND` instead of commas between the conditions in your `INNER JOIN`'s `ON` clause: `TableA.ColA = TableB.ColA AND TableA.ColB =TableB.ColB` instead of `TableA.ColA = TableB.ColA, TableA.ColB =TableB.ColB`  If you use Design View of the Access query designer to set up your joins, it should give you proper syntax for the `ON` clause.

Comment: Add indexes on the join fields.

Comment: Do your initial query testing with smaller copies of those data tables ... a few dozen rows instead of 20,000 to 40,000.

Comment: Further to comments from @HansUp - Your first example won't work at all ("Syntax error (comma) in query expression ...") and your second example cannot use indexes so it will always do table scans and that will be slow.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comments, the above are not the actual queries taken from the tool, they are for illustrating the problem, rather than asking for verification of the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't how performance would compare to what you've tried, but in a similar situation I use a UNION query to set up the data, a 2nd query based on the UNION to summarize the data and a 3rd to get the variances.  An additional feature, and the reason I do it this way, is that it finds records in either table that don't match the other table - which I usually need to know.  Note - I used 0 assuming that ColE is numeric, and you may need to adjust the queries if your data is text.

UNION:

```
 Select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE as SourceA, 0 as SourceB from TableA
    Union All Select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, 0, ColE from TableB
```

SUMMARY:

```
Select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, sum(SourceA) as SourceA, sum(SourceB) as SourceB from UNION
```

COMPARE:

```
Select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, SourceA, SourceB from SUMMARY where ((SourceA <> SourceB) or (SourceA is null) or (SourceB is null))
```

Comment: Thanks Don George.